# If the string '%2b' exists in the URL alias, does it affect SEO of the page?

Tags: seo, url

I have a platform which uses a responsive design. The structure of the website is like this: `Domain/#!/Product_type/Product_ID`

Here, I am trying to create the alias URL (Using an earlier version of Drupal) where I replace `<Product ID>` with `<Product Name>`. This is not possible, since the URL structure in the responsive page and the earlier Drupal version doesn't match. One fix which my team suggested is creating an alias URL in this format.

```
 Domain/#!/Product_type%2bProduct_ID
```

where `%2b` is the unicode version of the `/`. I want to know if structuring the URL with a `%2b` will affect the SEO of the page in any way.

Comment: Short answer? No. You should be fine.

Comment: "`%2b` is the unicode version of the `/`" - `%2b` is a _percent encoded_ `+`.

Answer (score 2):

While in the end both "/" and "%2f" represent the same character, search engine robots will treat both URLs independently (they are technically not the same). For example you will get two hits on your server by Googlebot instead of one (I have lots of server logs which prove this).

In the end it's the same issue as with all "nearly the same" URLs: It's a canonicalization thing ([see Google's documentation about this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)). The impact on your SEO depends heavily on the exact situation.

Generally speaking you should try to get rid of the differing URL schemes. You could also for example use a canonical tag as a workaround.

EDIT: "/" in unicode is "%2f"

Answer (score 0):

No, you should be ok. It won't have a specific impact on your SEO.

Answer (score 0):

So as you said in your Question: The `%2b`is only the Unicode representation of `+` so everything (a computer) will read here also a `+` because it will be encoded into the internal Character-Encoding ... so it is only a representation an will not affect your SEO - however it's not beautiful for your humans.

So far - I'm sorry that I'm not allowed to talk more about the internals